# Expansion of $C^j B^k$ for non-commutative $C$ and $B$ such that all $B$s are left of $C$s?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be some operators (*details not relevant*) and $\alpha$ a constant. The operators obey the following commutation relations:

$$ [A,B]=\alpha I $$
$$ [C,B]=2A$$
$$ [A,C]=0$$

I want to expand the following product

$$ C^j B^k $$

as a sum of terms where all $B$s are left of all $A$s and all $A$s are left of all $C$s, but I have no idea how to proceed... I tried expanding it by hand, but it gets complicated way too quickly and I can't spot a pattern. All help would be **greatly** appreciated!

By the way, $j,k \geq 0 $ and $j$ can be either less, equal, or greater than $k$.

Comment: What did you get for $C^2B,C^2B^2,$ etc. ?

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm a sloppy physicist :) Edited! I'll write in a minute what I got for that.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You asked this on purpose, didn't you? I got exactly the same answer as if $C$ and $B$ commuted with each other!